# I want to save the report to the SQl Server database automatically from the DevExpress report designer interface

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, report, devexpress, designer

I created a table in the database that contains the fields shown in the attached image and stored some reports in it, but the storage path was from the device files. I want to save the report automatically from the report designer interface in DevExpress.
I have added a button for the user and I want the user to click on it to save the report available in the report designer directly to the report table in the database, knowing that I use C# and Entity FreamWork.

I tried to assign the values ​​of the report to variables, but I do not have sufficient knowledge about how to control the name of the report in the Report Designer, as well as the report data itself, and how to save it directly to the database through the button that I added to the Report Designer interface.

Comment: You have forgotten to attach the image